# Example of the two uniformly equivalent metrics, one is bounded while another is not.

Tags: uniform-continuity

Can anyone gives me an example such that two metric space *(X,d1)*, *(X,d2)* are uniformly equivalent. And the metric space *(X,d1)* is bounded and metric space *(X,d2)* is not bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\Bbb R, \min\{|x - y|,1\})$ and $(\Bbb R, |x - y|)$.

I'll leave it to you to show that the first is indeed a metric. The equivalence should be obvious. The same trick works for converting any unbounded metric on any metric space to a bounded one.